# Can I use pip install to install a module for another users?

Tags: python, pip

I'm wish to install Numpy for the `www-data` user, but I can not log into this user using `login`. How can I make `www-data` make us of the Numpy module?

To clarify. Numpy is available for root, and for my default user.

Comment: if you have sudo rights, `sudo pip install numpy` should install the package for every user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running `pip` with `sudo` should install a package for all users

```
sudo pip install numpy
```

If it doesn't work, try

```
sudo -H -u www-data pip install --user numpy
```

which should install numpy only for `www-data`

Answer (score 0):

you will find your answer [here](https://packaging.python.org/installing/#installing-to-the-user-site) :

```
pip install --user numpy
```

Comment: www-data is not the current user, nor can I login as www-data to make it the current user.

Comment: That will install for his current user, not `www-data`

Comment: and a `sudo pip install numpy`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to switch to that user and run it with

`pip install --user package`

There is that one issue (you probably ran into) that you cant switch to some users because some users have `nologin shell`. But you can always switch to that user passing shell you want like this:

`sudo su -s /usr/bin www-data`