# Python script can't access library as www-data

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am running several flask apps on an Ubuntu 18.04 server with nginx and uwsgi workers in python 3.6. The overall architecture is as described in [this post](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/nginx/setup-nginx-and-uwsgi-for-flask-on-ubuntu/).

After deploying a new version of "myapp" the app quietly ceased to work. The logs generated by uwsgi show the terrifying "no python application found" error. Calling the URL resulted in an "Internal Server Error".

Calling the app directly from the terminal as the regular non-root user with `python3 myapp.py` in an activated virtual environment worked fine. I assumed that uwsgi calls the app as www-data and tried `sudo -u www-data python3 myapp.py`. Finally, the app refuses to fire up.

```
(env) user@server:~/projects/myapp$ python3 myapp.py 
* Serving Flask app "MyApp" (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
  WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: off
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
^C(env) user@server:~/projects/myapp$ sudo -u www-data python3 myapp.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "myapp.py", line 20, in <module>
   import post
 File "/home/oliver/projects/myapp/post.py", line 5, in <module>
   import qrcode
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qrcode'
```

I pip3-uninstalled and re-installed qrcode[pil] in the activated environment. I even sudo installed qrcode[pil] systemwide in an act of desperation.

So my question: **is there a way to install the library qrcode[pi] in a way the script can import it as www-data? Is my assumption calling the script as www-data to debug mainly allright?**

Thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: My first solution would be to check if the virtual environment directory is readable by www-data, but it seems that qrcode is not installed at all. Can you check that qrcode is installed in your virtual env by running pip list inside of it?

Comment: Thank you for helping out so quickly. While poking at the virtual environment the app broke with more and more errors. I will re install the virtual environment and come back with a listing.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for asking, unluckily no. I Updated the question with the details. Please note the different formatting and in the www-data user version even flask is missing. Can there be a glitch in a path definition? It's funny because 5 apps on the server are running without the slightest hickup.

Comment: You should take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44306821/9515831 But it looks like *user* is trying to run the app, not *www-data*. Does *user*have the correct permissions? Inside your virtualenv what command did you use for installing modules?

Comment: Hey Victor. Thanks for pointing out the "-H" flag. Actually, ```sudo -H -u www-data pip install --user qrcode[pil]``` within the virtualenv refused to work ```OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: /var/www/.local```. Going up the permission ladder I tried the brutal way ```sudo -H -u www-data pip install qrcode[pil]``` OUTSIDE the virtualenv. That seemed to do the trick. Not very elegant, thus effective. No I can try to tackle the next errors. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Wohoo. Brought it back to life. This verified the assumption that (if uWSGI accesses the app as www-data) ```sudo -u www-data python3 myapp.py``` gives a hint on permission problems if the app dies silently without any logs.